# How long does it take to capture 42 balls if it takes 5 mins in average to capture 1

Tags: self-study

I saw this problem somewhere and I don't really know what to do with it. Here is the question:

Suppose that there is 42 Pokémon balls and that in average it takes you 5 minutes to catch one ball. How long does it take before you capture all 42 balls? You can use any software you like but be sure to state your assumptions.

I don't know where to begin honestly. I was thinking maybe I would create a random variable for this 42 balls. So maybe $X_i$ signifies the time taken to catch ball $i$ and that I can only be able to catch one ball at a time. So what I will be ultimately computing is $Z_i = X_1 +...+X_n$

I am thinking that $X_i$ ~ Normal distribution with mean 5, but I don't know what to do with the variance. I cant really think of any distribution with one parameter that might be appropriate. Then I am thinking to generate numbers with R from this distribution.

Clearly I don't know what to do exactly with the problem so if anyone has any thoughts, I would love to hear it!

Comment: I would begin by contemplating the "obvious" answers and pushing them to extremes.  For instance, why shouldn't the answer be $42\times 5$ minutes?  In a model where you focus on capturing one ball and then turn to capturing the next and the next..., that would seem to be the right answer.  What about $5$ minutes? Although that seems ridiculous--$42$ isn't even considered--it strikes me that if I could set about capturing any number of balls with a set of operations running in parallel, then I might indeed be able to capture $42$ in as much time as one.

Comment: ... At one extreme, suppose I set a trap to capture randomly moving balls.  If it takes $5$ minutes to capture one, then maybe it will take $5\times 42$ to capture the very last one--and intermediate amounts of time to capture all $42$ of them. That would require over $15$ hours total. Another thought is maybe it takes $5$ minutes to capture one ball because the other $41$ are getting in the way.  Possibly the capture time *decreases* as balls are caught. That could lead to a solution taking under two hours, depending on how the capture time varies with the number of interfering balls.

Comment: That's true though I didn't think of the latter case. When you say if it takes 5 to capture one and 5x42 to capture the last one, wont that mean that the average ball caught wont be 5 mins? Honestly I wouldn't know how to model it though

Comment: It depends on how you interpret "on the average it takes you 5 minutes to capture one ball."  Does this mean it takes you $42\times 5$ minutes to capture all $42$ balls, or does it mean that in many similar situations the average time taken to capture *just one ball* is $5$ minutes?  There is a lot of latitude for interpreting and modeling this question. The important part of it seems to be the exhortation to identify and state your assumptions.